# Excel 2010 - Copy all rows with a name in a cell to a worksheet with same name

Tags: vba, copy, excel-2010, worksheet

I have a team worksheet with data for the whole team.

### TEAM UPDATED 2/21/14    FEBRUARY 2014

#### BLAH   BLAH    BLAH    NAME    BLAH     BLAH

1. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BOB    BLAH    BLAH
2. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    JOE    BLAH    BLAH
3. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BOB    BLAH    BLAH
4. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BOB    BLAH    BLAH
5. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    SUE    BLAH    BLAH
6. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BOB    BLAH    BLAH
7. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    JOE    BLAH    BLAH
8. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    JOE    BLAH    BLAH
9. BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    SUE    BLAH    BLAH

There are several worsheets within the same workbook with each persons name.
I want to automatically copy the headers and all of the rows that belong to each person and put them into that persons worksheet.

I know each person can sort the TEAM worksheet and get their own data, but I work with some "special" people.  So when I update the TEAM sheet, I want it to automatically update each persons worksheet.

My main issue is that I am very new to VB (self learning).  Ive done a couple of other things, but am still learning.

Thanks for any help.

I recorded the below macro that works for one person:

```
Sub SortbyCSRName()
'
' SortbyCSRName Macro
' This will sort all data by CSR name
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Rows("2:1618").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Team Total").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Team Total").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "G3:G1618"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Team Total").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:S1618")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Connie"
    Sheets("Team Total").Select
    Rows("3:51").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Connie").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

The range of cells will differ from time to time, but I assume Excel will adjust for that.

I also found a macro that Im not sure how to adapt to what I need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, cc
Dim temp As Worksheet, CostC As Range, u

Set ws = Sheets("Team Total") 'where your original data. adjust to suit
Set Rng = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 15)
Set CostC = ws.Range("G3", ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

u = UNIQUE(CostC)
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
For Each cc In u
    With Rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & cc
        On Error Resume Next
        Set temp = Sheets(cc)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then

DoThis:

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy temp.Range("A1")
        Else
            Set temp = Sheets.Add
            temp.Name = cc
            GoTo DoThis
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Set temp = Nothing
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub

Function UNIQUE(r As Range)
Dim a, v
If IsArray(r.Value) Then
    a = r.Value
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = vbTextCompare
        For Each v In a
            If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                If Not .exists(v) Then .Add v, Nothing
            End If
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then UNIQUE = .keys
    End With
    Erase a
Else
    UNIQUE = r.Value
End If

End Function
```

2/24/14
I get Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

The culprit - Set WS1 = WB.Sheets(CStr(Key))

```
Sub TransferToPersonalSheets()

    Dim WB As Workbook: Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim R0 As Range, RName As Range, RCell As Range
    Dim Dict As Object

    Set WS0 = WB.Sheets("Team Total") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set R0 = WS0.Range("A3:O1618") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set RName = R0.Range("G3:G1618") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each RCell In RName
        If Not Dict.Exists(RCell.Value) Then
            Dict.Add RCell.Value, Empty
        End If
    Next RCell

    For Each Key In Dict
        WS0.AutoFilterMode = False
        ApplyFilter R0, 4, CStr(Key)
        Set WS1 = WB.Sheets(CStr(Key))
        R0.Offset(1, 0).Copy WS1.Range("A3")
    Next Key

    WS0.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub

Sub ApplyFilter(Rng As Range, ColIndex As Long, StrName As String)
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=ColIndex, Criteria1:=StrName, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many ways to cook a [insert generic item]. What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't really about writing entire macros - it is about helping with particular issues you are having in implementing or conceiving of a solution. Please post the code of what you have tried and we can help improve it.

Comment: As a starting pointer, and depending on your VBA experience, I suggest condsidering either a) loading all the data into an array and then looping through the array adding to a collection of collections (the collection is of a collection per person) then dumping from each collection into their sheet, or b) using the .Autofilter method to get Excel to extract each person's relevant rows, then copying those rows over to their sheet.

Comment: On second thoughts, as you are new to VBA, I recommend using the macro recorder to record you filtering and copying one person's rows to their sheet. Then look at the code and try and adapt it into a loop to do the same for all people. Even posting the macro recorder code output of the above gives us something to work.

Comment: I think creating a pivot table would be the simplest method of accomplishing what you are looking to do, just create a dynamic range (or manually update it, your choice) for the source and filter each persons report on their name, then hide the rows that contain the filter options so they don't go changing everything around.

Comment: As I said, I am new to VBA and am very leery about using the macro recorder.I will work on the pivot table and post what I come up with.

Comment: What's the name of the sheet containing the data and which column is the name? `D:D`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (***tried and tested***):

**Code:**

```
Sub TransferToPersonalSheets()

    Dim WB As Workbook: Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim R0 As Range, RName As Range, RCell As Range
    Dim Dict As Object

    Set WS0 = WB.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set R0 = WS0.Range("A1:F20") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set RName = R0.Range("D2:D20") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each RCell In RName
        If Not Dict.Exists(RCell.Value) Then
            Dict.Add RCell.Value, Empty
        End If
    Next RCell

    For Each Key In Dict
        WS0.AutoFilterMode = False
        ApplyFilter R0, 4, CStr(Key)
        Set WS1 = WB.Sheets(CStr(Key))
        R0.Offset(1, 0).Copy WS1.Range("A2")
    Next Key

    WS0.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub

Sub ApplyFilter(Rng As Range, ColIndex As Long, StrName As String)
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=ColIndex, Criteria1:=StrName, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub
```

**Logic:**

The concept is simple: We create a unique list of names using a dictionary. For each name stored in the dictionary, we apply an `AutoFilter` on the range in question with criteria equals to the name. This nets us the range we want for each user.

We then target the sheet named after the user stored in the current key, and we copy the filtered rows to the targeted sheet. We repeat this action until all names are copied.

**Screenshots:**

***Set-up:***

[image]

***After running code:***

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Kindly ***edit*** your original post to reflect the error. Reading code in the comments is an absolute pain. Indicate on which line it's throwing the error as well.